# Remove Non Standard character from begining or end of string

Tags: php

I am trying to manipulate some sentences, and I can remove the non standard characters from a string, but is there any way to do this only if it is at the beginning or end of a string?  To remove non standard characters I am using the following:

```
 preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

I would like to change a string like this:

"* This is a sentence. --"

To be this:

"This is a sentence."

Comment: You could do something like this `(^[^A-Za-z0-9 ,.]*)|([^A-Za-z0-9 ,.]*$)` The key points are the ^ says only in the beginning, the | says or this regex, and the $ says it has to be at the end. You would probably be better off if you knew what needed to be stripped out before hand or you could sanitize the data before it got to this point.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, Ill give that a try.  Unfortunately I cannot sanitize the data it is coming from OCR data directly from a scanned document so there is always going to be some craziness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't 100% robust, but this works:

```
preg_replace("/(?:^[^A-z0-9]+|[^.A-z0-9]+$)/", "", $input_lines);
```

[Demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/87c)

Basically, it's replacing either anything at the beginning for the line that isn't A-z, 0-9 with '' (since there are no matching groups) or (`|`) at the end anything after a full stop that isn't 0-9, A-z.